# Best way to store bitmaps

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

Right now I have some classes that are in charge of keeping the internal memory bitmaps which are then listed in ListViews.

Upon listing, resort to a method that tell what the name of the image you want to return and receive the corresponding bitmap.

When the application starts, load into memory (HashMap ) all the images you'll need, once you load the image from the internal memory directly to the listview, the process takes a long time.

I am using the recycling of views and each item has two and two imageviews textviews. However, the scrooll is very slow and has a lot of lag.

It is a good solution to have the images in memory (hashmap)? For loading into memory at the time of the list is even slower. The images have 100x100 pixels.

My question is: My problem with lag may have to do with the fact that the images are all in memory? What is the best solution?

**EDIT:**

```
07-25 16:56:33.195: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.195: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.203: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.203: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.210: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.257: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [16]
07-25 16:56:33.265: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [15]
07-25 16:56:33.273: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [14]
07-25 16:56:33.281: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.289: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.289: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.289: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.296: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.296: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.304: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [6]
07-25 16:56:33.312: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [7]
07-25 16:56:33.320: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.328: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.328: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.335: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.335: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.343: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.343: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [6]
07-25 16:56:33.359: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.359: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.367: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.367: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.367: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.375: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.382: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [6]
07-25 16:56:33.398: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.398: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.406: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.406: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.414: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.414: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.484: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [13]
07-25 16:56:33.492: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.500: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.500: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.507: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.507: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.507: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.515: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [6]
07-25 16:56:33.523: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [7]
07-25 16:56:33.531: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.539: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.539: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.546: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.546: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.554: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.554: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [6]
07-25 16:56:33.562: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.570: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.578: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.578: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.578: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.585: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.585: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [6]
07-25 16:56:33.609: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.609: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.617: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.617: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.625: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.625: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.679: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [12]
07-25 16:56:33.687: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.695: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.695: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.703: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.703: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.710: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.710: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [6]
07-25 16:56:33.718: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [7]
07-25 16:56:33.734: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.734: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.742: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.742: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.750: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.750: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.757: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [6]
07-25 16:56:33.765: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.773: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.773: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.773: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.781: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.781: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.789: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [6]
07-25 16:56:33.804: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.812: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.812: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.812: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.820: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.820: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.875: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.882: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.890: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.890: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.898: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.898: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.906: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [6]
07-25 16:56:33.914: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [7]
07-25 16:56:33.929: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.929: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.937: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.937: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.945: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.953: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.953: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [6]
07-25 16:56:33.968: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:33.976: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:33.976: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:33.976: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:33.984: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:33.984: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
07-25 16:56:33.992: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [6]
07-25 16:56:34.007: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [0]
07-25 16:56:34.015: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [1]
07-25 16:56:34.015: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [2]
07-25 16:56:34.015: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [3]
07-25 16:56:34.023: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [4]
07-25 16:56:34.031: V/ADAPTER(8648): recicling view [5]
```

Whenever I scroll (the list goes on), I get this output. where the content within [] corresponds to the position. Is not it strange that he is constantly showing the position 0-6?

**EDIT**

Now discovered a possible reason.

I am currently a tab_activity, where have all the necessary views.
In the xml added a tab_activity top_bar, where I have an image that is constantly being changed. When the image is in automatic mode (constantly being changed), the ListViews that are within a tab, is "repainted", hence the lag.

I am using a service (music) that changes the image of x in x time.

Why are ListViews to be repainted when I view an image is repainted?

Comment: Do your images have large file sizes? And are they in a supported optimised format? .png files are recommended

Comment: fos = openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos); I use JPEG to save images, its wrong? And i use: bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis); to get image from internal storage

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the loading of the images is causing the lag, yet if it is, then I suggest you create some sort of UI that reports to the user that the images are loading.
(To check wether the images are causing the lag, I suggest you have a look at DDMS are simply log with the LogCat)

I use the following code to save bitmaps to the memory:

The following will write to the memory:

```
public void writeBitmapToMemory(String filename, Bitmap bitmap) {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        // Use the compress method on the Bitmap object to write image to the OutputStream
        try {
            fos = game.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
            // this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Bitmap successfully written: " + filename);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Bitmap couldn't be written: " + filename);

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Bitmap couldn't be written: " + filename);

        }

    }
```

this will read from the memory:

```
public Bitmap readBitmapFromMemory(String filename) {
        Bitmap defautBitmap = null;
        File filePath = game.getFileStreamPath(filename);
        FileInputStream fi;
        try {
            fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            defautBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);
            // this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Bitmap successfully read: " + filename);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Bitmap couldn't be opened: " + filename);
        }

        return defautBitmap;

    }
```